# better way to find pattern in string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have two strings from which I want to extract IPs.

These are:

```
a = """+CGCONTRDP: 1,0,"open.internet","100.80.54.162.255.255.255.255","100.80.54.162","8.8.8.8
","62.40.32.33","0.0.0.0","0.0.0.0",0

OK
"""
b = """+UIPADDR: 1,"usb0:0","100.80.54.93","255.255.255.255","",""

OK
"""
```

From the first I want `100.80.54.162` and the second I want `100.80.54.162`.
Now obviously lengths of numbers in an IP changes. For the moment I am spitting on `","` and finding the numbers before the first 4 `.`'s. What is a better way to do this as it seems dirty, perhaps the first occurrence of digits.digits.digits.digits and stopping at the next non digit character, a pattern looking for that? How would you do it?

Comment: look at the `re` module, for regex

Comment: thanks I meant was the method I was thinking of for re the most robust, I guess it is a trivial question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to match the first four dot-separated numbers in your string, then it's trivial:

```
>>> re.search(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", a).group()
'100.80.54.162'
```

If you want to do some additional checking (only allowing numbers between 0 and 255), you can:

```
>>> re.search(r"""(?x)\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.
...                     (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.
...                     (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.
...                     (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b""", b).group()
'100.80.54.93'
```

Comment: re.findall will also do .+1 for extra validation

Comment: The extra validation answer is great, i want more robustness, thanks!

Comment: @vks: He only wants to find the first one, it seems, so `re.findall` wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @vks Err no? findall doesn't return an object but a list.

Comment: in what cases would leaving out \b's and ?x match any differently?

Comment: @Paul: If you leave out `(?x)`, you won't get any matches because the linebreaks become part of the regex if you do. If you leave out the `\b` [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), then you might match part of incorrect strings like `1234.56.78.910`